# how to use conditional inclusion statements in headers used in RcppEigen project

Tags: c++, eigen, rcpp, preprocessor, rcppeigen

I have an [RcppEigen package](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfexamplesinr) that has a bunch of `.h` header files in it that I copy/pasted from [my other library](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pf). These header files exist in two places, and right now there is only one difference between copies. In the pure c++ library, I include Eigen with `#include <Eigen/Dense>`. However, in the RcppEigen project, I need to use `#include <RcppEigen.h>`.

The problem with the naive solution--to hold on to two nearly-dentical copies of all these header files--is that I have a lot of code duplication.

To fix that I want to include the pure c++ library as a git submodule in the RcppEigen package. I would like to edit the c++ library to use conditional inclusion statements, so that they can be included in both pure c++ projects, as well as RcppEigen projects. I envision something like the following at the tops of the header files:

```
#ifdef DROPPINGTHISINRPACKAGE
    #include <RcppEigen.h>
#else
    #include <Eigen/Dense>
#endif
```

I'm confused what I should use for `DROPPINGTHISINRPACKAGE`, though. What is the customary way to do this in RcppEigen packages? What kinds of things are defined by the preprocessor in these kinds of packages that I can use?

Edit:

`sourceCpp` appears (to me) to be skipping over these flags being set in [`Makevars`](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfexamplesinr/blob/master/src/Makevars). Running `Rcpp::sourceCpp(file = "~/pfexamplesinr/src/likelihoods.cpp")` fails and complains that certain features are only available in c++17. It points to the spot in a header from the c++ library:

```
            #ifndef DROPPINGTHISINRPACKAGE
            if constexpr(debug) 
                std::cout << "time: " << m_now << ", transposed sample: " << m_particles[ii].transpose() << ", log unnorm weight: " << m_logUnNormWeights[ii] << "\n";
            #endif
```

Comment: A fairly common trick is to define 'something' in `src/Makevars{,.win}` to indicate the 'from R' compilation -- your first case.

Comment: So to be plain:  add a line `PKG_CPPFLAGS=-DDROPPINGTHISINRPACKAGE` and you should be done.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel does Makevars get skipped over when I compile with `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`? I didn't notice the flag pop up when I was looking at the build commands, and my attempt to hide c++17 code with `#ifndef DROPPINGTHISINRPACKAGE`
failed

Comment: Yes of course it does. `sourceCpp()` is for one-offs, _has its manual page telling you how to se a `#define` too_ and it is generally well-established that a reall 'project' (your term, from you subject line) should be a package.